# problems connecting through vncviewer

Tags: vnc

I am currently connecting ok, but all that displays is a black screen in windows vncviewer. I looked at the log and this is what I got. Can someone help explain?

```
Sun Oct 31 16:20:01 2010
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on port 5801
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /usr/lib64/xserver/SecurityPolicy
sh: /home/andrew/.vnc/xstartup: Permission denied
Could not init font path element unix/:7100, removing from list!
AUDIT: Sun Oct 31 16:20:06 2010: 28746 Xvnc: client 1 rejected from local host
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: -1
```

Comment: it was a chmod issue with /home/andrew/.vnc/xstartup. sorted

Comment: Please answer the question and mark it as answered to close this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on the xstartup file, it sounds like you can't read it.